# How to reference an object that was created in a different object

Tags: python

I am testing my two classes with a file called test.py. I am just learning programming so this is just a practice program. There is one atlas(map) and i can put multiple 'robots' inside one map.

```
#test.py
from Atlas import Atlas
atlas = Atlas()
atlas.add_robot('rbt1')


#atlas.py
from Robot import Robot

class Atlas:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def add_robot(self, robot, zone = 'forrest'):
        self.robot = Robot(robot)
        print 'added robot %s to %s' % (robot, zone)


#robot.py
class Robot():

    def __init__(self, rbt, zone = 'forrest'):
        self.name = rbt
        print "%s initiated" % rbt

    def step(self, direction):
        ...
```

I use the code "atlas.add_robot('rbt1')" to put a new robot inside the atlas.

I want to be able to control the robot with a command such as "rbt1.step('left')" in test.py.

Comment: You know, in your code an `Atlas` object can only have one robot because any call to `add_robot` overwrites the previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your robot in test.py with `newRobot = Robot('rbt1')`, then do `atlas.add_robot(newRobot)`. To do this, we pass in a whole robot, not a robot name. Atlas should not be trying to initialize robots, because it is an Atlas. It should just worry about what Atlases do: keep track of where robots are.

A good concept to learn in programming is which pieces of code are allowed to touch something. In this case, we will create the robot in test.py (so we can touch it), then pass it to an Atlas (so the Atlas can touch it). That is effectively the heart of your question. Here are some general ways to deal with this problem:

- refactor your code, by changing the control flow, so you don't have this problem (like I demo below)
- pass in parameters / accessors - ask the object to give you the robot which matches what you know about it (in this case, a name)
- shallow data structure - the Atlas would be a shallow shell that behaves like a dictionary, and you'd just treat it like a dictionary (as opposed to doing `yourAtlas.robotsToZones(...)` below)
- abuse of globals - never do this, it is terrible programming
- closures - if you define a function inside a function (maybe even a class inside a class, but that gets ugly), the inner functions can access variables in the outer functions, though you have to use the `nonlocal` keyword in python to declare your intent to do this

To change the control flow so you don't have this problem: the Atlas can be made more flexible by passing in a fully-made Robot. It is an Atlas after all. Why would an Atlas be in charge of making Robots?

```
from collections import *

class Atlas(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.zones = defaultdict(set)

    def add_robot(self, robot, zone='forest')
        self.robots[zone].add(robot)
```

Alternatively you could do this:
(probably better since we probably expect robots to change zones)

```
class Atlas(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.robotsToZones = {}

    def add_robot(self, robot, zone='forest')
        self.robotsToZones[robot.name] = zone

    def robotsInWorlds(self):
        return self.robotsToZones.keys()  # .keys() not necessary, but hides representation
```

(if you care about speed you could actually do both... but you usually shouldn't care about speed, and that would require making sure both structures are in sync)

Also you should have data exist in just one spot. In your case, both the Robot and Atlas need to know which zone a robot is in. This is bad because *you must make sure those two values are always equal and in sync*, leading to needless headaches and complications, even maybe bugs. The solution is to ignore which zone a robot is in, in robot.py:

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

A Robot should never need to figure out where it is; that's the job of the atlas. If test.py needs to know where a Robot is, it can do something like `myAtlas.whereIs(myRobot)`, which can just `return self.robotsToZones[robot.name]`. This is known as *modularization* and *separation of concerns*.

(sidenote: The above assumes that you have some other mechanism to track which robots are in which zones, and you don't have coordinates. If you have your `step()` function deal with coordinates, you'll have to decide whether you have global or per-zone coordinates. The latter case is probably easier since all you need to define is how the boundaries of zones stitch together; though you can do the first case if you have the Atlas define non-overlapping (ick, possible bugs) boundaries for which zone is where. You can also maybe do something like have signposts which define zone boundaries, and a Robot is in the zone of the closest signpost. Though having each zone be made of equally-sized rectangles, representable via a grid, is probably easiest.)

Comment: That's not how his code is structured though.  He'd have to rewrite Atlas to make that work as well.

Comment: I wrote a suggested version of Atlas while sr2222 posted his/her comment.

Comment: +1 about not putting the zone information in the robot.  The robot can have a location, and the location can be in a zone, but the zone should not be stored in the robot itself.

Comment: This is, of course, supposition, but my guess is that a robot could move between zones.  I would suggest instead of `self.robotsToZones[robot.name] = zone`, each `Robot` should have a location, and then Atlas should track which locations are in which zones.

Comment: This is a great explanation of how this should be structured and you helped me understand why it should be this way. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @sr2222: Ah yes, that was my reason for suggesting `robotsToZones`. =) I'll mention your location comment in my answer.

Comment: @user1082764: No problem; you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq ; I've never tried it but I seems like a good resource if you're starting out programming, and wish to see how people make sure their programs are organized cleanly. The only downside I can think of is that more elegant code (e.g. `itertools`, functional programming) might be lost in the noise, and the important skill of Googling for tutorials/howtos may not improve (albeit it's hard to find "good practices" in search results...).

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding your robots to a list in `Atlas`.  Instead of `self.robot = Robot(robot)`, add `robots = []` to `Atlas.__init__()` and do `self.robots.append(Robot(robot))` in `Atlas.add_robot(robot)`.  Then you can access them through the list (`atlas.robots[0].step()`, `atlas.robots[1].step()`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to refer to the robot created within `atlas` by `atlas.robot`, because that's where you stored it.  You can create a new variable pointing to that like so:

```
rbt1 = atlas.robot
```

Then you should be able to refer to it as you described:

```
rbt1.step('left')
```

Note that if you want `atlas` to be able to have multiple robots, you should consider storing your robots in a `list` or `dict` object within `atlas`.